# Collapsible set Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I have the following collapsible header on my page and currently when you click on the set it expands and collapses. What i want is the javascript to have the set collapse when you click on one of the list items rather than go back to the top to collapse it. Is this possible?

```
<div data-role="collapsible" class="ui-collapsible-collapsed ui-block-a" id="my-collapsible">

                <h2>
                <a href="#111" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="false" data-theme="c">

                </a>
                </h2>
                <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-c ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g">

                        <li id="topnav4"><a id="tempshellstempb" onclick='changeshellsb();'></a></li>
                        <li id="topnav4"><a id="tempstarstempb"  onclick='changestarsb();' ></a></li>
                        <li id="topnav4"><a id="temppeacocktempb" onclick='changeIt();'></a></li>
                        <li id="topnav4"><a id="tempshootstarsb" onclick='changechestb();'></a></li>
                        <li id="topnav4"><a id="tempbrickstempb" onclick='changerosesb();'></a></li>
                        <li id="topnav4"><a id="tempforresttempb" onclick='changepeacockb();'></a></li>

                    </ul> 

                </div></div>
```

Comment: can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @trevor its not really an issue, just a question on how to make the list items collapse the set upon click. When you click on the header it collapses and expands the content but i also want it to collapse when you click on <a id="tempshellstempb" for example

Comment: @Steven so you want it to expand and collapse by clicking on any item or element within the collapsing div? Yes that is possible, what plugin is currently handling the collapsing for you? Are you going off of this plugin? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html

Comment: @ermagana yes i am using that plugin

Comment: The documentation here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#entry-examples doesn't say there are any api's to interact with the collapsible element, but if it's hooking into dom listeners and such you should be able to find the trigger that can be called to collapse the set.. sorry i couldn't be more helpful

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can trigger a collapse.

```
$('#tempshellstempb').click(function(){  
  //here you probably want to check to see if your selector is currently collapsed to decide whether your going to collapse or expand.
  // you can probably do this by checking the classes on your selector but i'm not too familiar with how jQuery-mobile handles this
  $( ".selector" ).trigger( "collapse" );
  //$( ".selector" ).trigger( "expand" );
});
```

Comment: @Steven please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question, otherwise give feedback on what is not resolved. Thanks